# Progress<T> Best usage practice

Tags: c#

I have a form that has a couple of progress bars and text labels used for updating the user during polling and copying tasks.

In order for me to update the form controls from a child worker class I decided to use IProgress/Progress for the first time and would like to know if what I am doing is ok or if there is a better more maintainable way?

MAIN FORM Code:

```
private Progress<int> NumFiles { get; set; }
private Progress<string> CurrentFile { get; set; }
private Progress<int> OverallProgress { get; set; }
private Progress<string> AverageIoSpeed { get; set; }
private Progress<string> UpdateTaskLabel { get; set; }
private Progress<int> CurrentFileProgress { get; set; }
private BulletTimeCopyOperations CopyOperations { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetFormFields();
}

private void SetFormFields()
{
    UpdateTaskLabel = new Progress<string>(value => lblTaskInfo.Text = value);
    NumFiles = new Progress<int>(value => lblNumFilesTotal.Text = value.ToString());
    CurrentFile = new Progress<string>(file => lblFilesProgress.Text = $"Copying File: {file}");
    CurrentFileProgress = new Progress<int>(fvalue => pbFilesProgress.Value = fvalue);
    OverallProgress = new Progress<int>(total => pbTotalProgress.Value = total);
    AverageIoSpeed = new Progress<string>(ioSpeed => lblSpeedAverage.Text = ioSpeed);
}


private void SetProgressMethods()
{
    OtherClass.SetTaskInfo = UpdateTaskLabel;
    OtherClass.ProgressNumberOfFiles = NumFiles;
    OtherClass.FileInUse = CurrentFile;
    OtherClass.CurrentProgress = CurrentFileProgress;
    OtherClass.TotalProgress = OverallProgress;
    OtherClass.TransferSpeed = AverageIoSpeed;
}


private void DoWork()
{
    //Call Set progress
    SetProgressMethods();
    
    //SOME TASKS.....
}
```

Worker Class:

```
public IProgress<string> SetTaskInfo { get; set; }
public IProgress<int> ProgressNumberOfFiles { get; set; }
public IProgress<string> FileInUse { get; set; }
public IProgress<int> CurrentProgress { get; set; }
public IProgress<int> TotalProgress { get; set; }
public IProgress<string> TransferSpeed { get; set; }



private async Task<bool> StartWork()
{
    //Do some work
    //Report some progress
    SetTaskInfo.Report("Long Running Tasks Running...");
    //And so on etc...
}
```

So I need to tidy things up and want to update a couple more controls and although this works fantastically well, I am thinking there may be a better way of implementing the above for multiple controls?

Comment: Does using a thing like a `Dictionary<Control, Progress<T>>` match your goal ? Perhaps creating a class having members instead, in addition to methods to manage the things ? And a List of these class instances ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Had not thought of using a dictionary so will test on that one, but I think your right on having a member class although things work great I believe there is always a better way for managing multiple items so thanks for the input its appreciated and useful

Comment: What do you think of the name *DisplayProgressManagedControl* for the class that will have Control and Delegate aggregated properties as well as some methods to handle and control the behavior and events, does it represents your pattern ? So using some list you will be able to automate to a certain extent.

Comment: Ah thanks once again @OlivierRogier I will say my naming conventions need some work so will actually use that ;) i have started separating into a managed class so there is a central control rather than a multitude of functions scattered around the main form class.

Thankyou Once again it really does help